# Visualforce PDF page break doesn't work

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, css

I'm creating Visualforce page rendered as PDF and struggling with page-break. I have a really long table which is stretched across 5-20 pages. The rows are rendered using `apex:repeat`. Source for repeat is list from extension. The table is organized in sections which could have from 4 to 7 rows. What I need is to avoid page brake in those sections. Code below should work as reference what what I have:

```
<table>
<apex:repeat value="{!lineItems}" var="lines">
    <apex:outputPanel render="{!lines.eader = true}" layout="none">
        <tr>
            <td>Blue row</td>
        </tr>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel render="{!lines.product = "1"}" layout="none">
        <tr>
            <td>white row 1</td>
        </tr>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel render="{!lines.product = "2"}" layout="none">
        <tr>
            <td>white row 2</td>
        </tr>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel render="{!lines.product = "3"}" layout="none">
        <tr>
            <td>white row 3</td>
        </tr>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel render="{!lines.summary = true}" layout="none">
        <tr>
            <td>Bold summary row</td>
        </tr>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```

What I want to is to avoid page break after all raws except last *Bold summary row*. If I put `page-break-inside/before/after:avoid` in the style of `<tr>` it will mess the table as picture below shows - looks like it pushed the row to next page but it somehow push more rows to overlay each other and left space before empty.
[image]

Is there another way to use page-break in such case?

Comment: Have you tried to assign `white-space: nowrap;` to each `td` element? You could exclude the last cell in each row using `td:last-child { white-space:  normal }`

Comment: Tried, didn't help. The result is little bit different but still is messed as on the picture. Also right border of table disappeared.